# Installing Elementary OS fails

Tags: elementary-os

I have been trying to install Elementary OS to my HP Spectre (2019) model. I have been getting ACPI errors but now, I get the errors shown in the pictures, had searched a lot but nothing worked, tried with both Rufus and Universal USB installer no solution. Please help me I hate Windows..

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like the installation media is buggered.

Comment: Are you installing in legacy or EFI mode?

Comment: I enabled the legacy support, now I used Unetbootin with internal hard drive boot, and after I choose Untetbootin, it gives error Windows can't be started!

Comment: What do you mean "I used Unetbootin with internal hard drive boot"? Did you copy the elementary OS image _to the hard drive_?

Comment: Yes,  to the hard drive

Answer (score 0):

The First thing that you need to specify is do you check the integrity of the downloaded iso file
if it has check see this [post](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/36484-solved-boot-failed-failed-to-load-ldlinuxc32/)